# What is the console command to advance the Werewolf skill?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

As the title says, I am looking for an ability to add experience to the werewolf skill.

I know that normally you can advance skill with the command

```
player.advskill <skillname> <amount>
```

However, this does not work when trying to advance the werewolf skill with

```
player.advskill werewolf 100
```

I also tried

```
player.advskill beastform 100
```

with no success.

Comment: +1 Had a look on the usual sites but couldn't find anything

Comment: Yup, I spent 2 hours googling for it and came up empty. A look into the creation kit also did not reveal the information I am looking for.

Comment: Don't suppose the console commands are case sensitive? Maybe try "Werewolf" instead of "werewolf"?

Comment: It's not a regular skill. It's probably tracked as a quest variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily get enough points to unlock every perk:

1. Open your console
2. Type "set DLC1WerewolfPerkPoints to XX" (xx = the number of actual perks your Werewolf tree contains, dependent on any mods you may have installed. Vanilla has 11 total perks, Bloodmoon Rising mod has 23, etc.)

And there you have it. Happy werewolfing.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. Answer with new, relevant to question information are always welcome on our site.

Answer (score 2):

The werewolf perk tree is a set of perks, not a skill. To gain a perk via the console, find its [perk ID](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lycanthropy#Skill_Perks) and use the `addperk` console command. The perks are listed starting with `xx` – those should be replaced by the load order of your Dawnguard plugin. For example, to add the Animal Vigor perk when the plugin is in the `03` plugin slot, use the command

```
player.addperk 030059a5
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, you can bump up your number of feedings with `set DLC1WerewolfFeedPoints to XX`. (You may also want to use `show DLC1WerewolfFeedPoints` first to see how many you have, then add to it.)

This is useful for when you forgot to feed on all the corpses before leaving a dungeon and the corpses had disappeared before you realized it. You can estimate the number of people you would have fed from and just add it to the total. If this would advance you by one or more levels, you'll need to feed to gain the perks. Debateably, this can be considered less of a cheat than the others, since you're only correcting the number of feedings and not giving yourself whole perks for free.